# gwt in netbeans

Tags: java

can i install GWT in netbeans?

Comment: Is your question **if** you can install it, or **how** to install it? My random guess is that you can, if you try hard enough.

Comment: Why would you want to...? just use Eclipse `:P`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can INTEGRATE.
[ref 1](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-gwt.html)
[ref 2](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2007/12/developing-gwt-applications-with.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a plugin called GWT4NB: https://gwt4nb.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

GWT is independent from IDE. Is certain sense it doesn't need installation at all.

Just configure it as compiler for your porject.

Answer (score 0):

You can, there's a plugin for it:

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-gwt.html